# is there a way to launch excel from python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've written a script that produces an Excel Workbook, and I would like that workbook to open automatically once my script has run. is there a way for me to write that in python?

Here's a snippet of my code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

   k = df.loc[df['UniqueID'] == search]
    k = k.drop(['MobileNo_Avl_Flag', 'PRI.CURRENT.BALANCE', 'State_ID', 'DisbursalDate', 'Employment.Weight','asset_cost', 'disbursed_amount'], axis= 1)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("dashboard.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    k.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.insert_image('A3', 'open-book-clipart-blue-11.jpg')
    worksheet.set_column('A:S', 20)
    worksheet.write(0, 0, "Dashboard for the customer id you searched", )
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$E$2:$F$2'})
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#B3DEFD',
        'border': 1})
    for col_num, value in enumerate(k.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
    worksheet.insert_chart('J4', chart)
    writer.save()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the ```subprocess``` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Excel (or another program) using `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["C:/path/to/Excel.exe", "C:/path/to/workbook.xlsx"])
```

Note this code might not be portable to other environments, since it is dependent on your Excel install path.

Answer (score 1):

[os.startfile(*file*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) will launch a file as if double-clicked in Windows Explorer.

```
import os
os.startfile('dashboard.xlsx')
```

You may need a `writer.close()` before launching the file.